# Regular expression match a hyperlink of defined hypertext

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I'm trying to find a regex that matches an HTML hyperlink tag that has defined hypertext. For example:

```
<a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
```

I need to match any hyperlink that its hypertext is "The defined text".

I just found the following expression on [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1701) but it does not solved the issue.

```
<a.+?href\=(?<link>.+?)(?=[>\s]).*?>(?<lnkText>.+?)</a>
```

I hope a solution that works with PHP.

Comment: did you want href="blah blah" or only "blah blah" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$regex = "/<a\s.*href.*>The defined text<\/a>/"; //corrected as per the comments
$str = '<a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
    <a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The Not-defined text</a>
';

preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);

foreach($matches as $match) echo $match."<br/>";
```

It will match the whole string from

```
<a href
```

to the closing tag.

```
</a>
```

**EDIT**

TECHNICALLY the regex could just be:

```
$regex = "/<a\s.*>The defined text<\/a>/"
```

in fact this is probably better!

Thanks for the catch in the comments!

Comment: Thats what I was trying to answer (+1). Just a suggestion, I think is more efficient replace `a\shref` by `a.*\shref` (href is not restricted to be always the first..)

Comment: It solution not found <a rel="aaa" HREF="">text</a>

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this over-sight. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html='<a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The
defined text</a>';
preg_match_all("/<a.+?href\=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>The defined Text<\\/a>/",$html,$matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match) echo "Link found: " . $match;
```

It returns

> Link found: blah blah

If you want the array with all the matches:

```
$matches[1]
```

Comment: Yours is the closest among the answers. You might want to make a few improvements, namely change the first `.+?` to `[^>]+?` and make a capture group for the 'The defined Text'. Your method of getting the matches will have to change though, since you'll have two capture groups then.

Comment: I used your regex with `preg_replace` as follows: `echo preg_replace("/<a.+?href\=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*> بِسْمِ<\\/a>/", '99', $ayah['Quran']['AyahText'])` but it failed to replace the html tag of the hyperlink that its hypertext  بِسْمِ with 99 from the string defined in $ayah['Quran']['AyahText']

Answer (score 1):

**TRY this:**

DEMO LIVE: https://eval.in/85894

```
 $p = '/<a.*? (href=".*?").*?>The defined text<\/a>/';
    $str = '
       <a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text2</a>
    <a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>

    ';
    preg_match_all($p,$str,$m);
    print_r($m[1]);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => href="blah blah"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use this regex:

```
((?=<a.+href).*(?<=</a>))[^</a]
```

For global search you must add flag "g" and for disabling case sensitive flag "i"

As for php:

```
$html = '<a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
         <a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
         <a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
         <a href="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
         <a HREF="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a>
         <a anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue" href="blah blah">The defined text</a>';

preg_match('/((?=<a.+href).*(?<=</a>))[^</a]/gi', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

This solution for getting all links with href attribute, even if several "a" is placed at one line. Example:

```
<a HREF="blah blah" anyAttribute="" anyThingElse="anyValue">The defined text</a><a>asdasd</a>
```